# How to perform async bacpac extraction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

[SQL Azure BACPAC extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721514/sql-azure-bacpac-extraction)

I want to do the same as this question but using the async process on another thread.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Exporting a BACPAC is something that has to finish before you do anything else in your program, unless you are trying to export multiple databases at the same time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah that's exactly what I'm trying to do ... Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for "an async process on another thread" you could use tasks.

```
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
           //Your code here.
        });
```

Comment: That would be appropriate for CPU bound work, but not for network bound work.