# How to import bacpac to Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, bacpac

I have a bacpac file and I need to import bacpac to a dataset type variable.

I have checked [QL Azure BACPAC extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721514/sql-azure-bacpac-extraction), however I do not know how to use `ImportBacpac` command from `DacServices`:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
//csb.DataSource = "servername";
//csb.Password = "whatever";
//csb.UserID = "whatever";

DacServices ds = new DacServices(csb.ConnectionString);
ds.ImportBacpac()
```

There is no example in MSDN website for ImportBacpac [DacServices.ImportBacpac Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacservices.importbacpac(v=sql.120).aspx#M:Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.ImportBacpac%28Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage,System.String,Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacImportOptions,System.Nullable%7BSystem.Threading.CancellationToken%7D%29)

Then I discover another post [How to import Azure SQL backup (.bacpac) to LocalDB using Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850337/how-to-import-azure-sql-backup-bacpac-to-localdb-using-visual-studio)
The method in that post uses a command line involving SqlPackage.exe

How do I import/read that bacpac to Dataset using that command line method above in C#? Or have I missed something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So, I also had this problem, but I just solved it.
You have to send sourcefile using BacPackage.Load()
My example:

```
var ds = new DacServices(Csb.ConnectionString);
ds.ImportBacpac(BacPackage.Load(Path.Combine(directory + lastBacpacBackup.Name)),"DB_NAME", new DacImportOptions());
```

Remember, you can't keep database with the same database name as you want to create.

Comment: "you can't keep database with the same as you want to create" Looks like you are missing a word here. Same as what?

Comment: Maybe you can answer this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311105/creating-azure-db-with-huge-backpac-files